# How to edit a row in a table when i edit other?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

So basically I’m kind a new in Asp.net MVC and I’m learning the basics. I need to edit a row in my X table when I edit a row on the Y table

**Controller Edit**

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "DespesaId,TipoDespesaId,DespesaDescricao,DespesaValor,TipoPagamentoId,Data,Comentario")] Despesa despesa)
{
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(despesa).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.TipoDespesaId = new SelectList(db.TipoDespesas, "TipoDespesaId", "TipoDespesaNome", despesa.TipoDespesaId);
    ViewBag.TipoPagamentoId = new SelectList(db.TipoPagamentos, "TipoPagamentoId", "TipoPagamentoNome", despesa.TipoPagamentoId);
    return View(despesa);
}
```

Here I need to edit the row that has the same Id as the despise but in a different db. I need to do 2 edits here. How can I do that?

Comment: Get the record from that table using the same id, update the property values and save back.

Comment: can you show it with some code? for exmaple that ModelState.IsValid i dont know if i need it in that case

Comment: Sorry, your question is too vague to write any code. What exactly are you trying to achieve? When exactly do you need to edit both rows? How does the database model look like? If you are still learning the basics, maybe have a look at this tutorial: [Getting started with EF & MVC](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: i need to edit the 2nd row when the first is edited basicly, i just have no idea how to construct it, i know i need to create a object from my other table and then? must i do another db.Entry?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to edit the second row table, try to retrive concerned row, make changes and save it  as you do generally when saving data .

you can also use sql triggers.